# Impossible to get the latest build using Azure DevOps API

Tags: .net, azure, api, azure-devops

I'm trying to get it using this GET request:

```
https://dev.azure.com/LumiaWOA/Boot%20Shim/_apis/build/latest/UEFI%20PreLoader Build?branchName=msm8994-pcie&api-version=5.0-preview.1
```

All I get is this response:

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "Cannot serialize type Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.Build, because the security requirements are not met  Namespace:33344d9c-fc72-4d6f-aba5-fa317101a7e9, RequestedPermissions:1, DataspaceIdentifier: 328eea29-7d2f-4cdf-b928-d58c53d8f29d",
    "typeName": "System.InvalidOperationException, mscorlib",
    "typeKey": "InvalidOperationException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 0
}
```

I don't understand why I'm getting that error, since the builds are public for everyone: Please, check it: https://dev.azure.com/LumiaWoA/Boot%20Shim/_build?definitionId=3

But it shows this error.

Comment: i did tinker with it a bit, it looks like you need to auth to the api, i dont see any other explanation.

Comment: Authentication is a mandate part, which you ignored, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#authenticate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my test, I also can reproduce the issue as you mentioned. From the response error message 500. It is not relate to authentication. It seems there is something wrong with Azure Devops API from server side. I recommend that you could give [your feedback](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) to azure devops.

[image]

My workaround is that we could use the list build ways with `$top =1` to get the latest build. For more information please refer to [List build API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0).

```
https://dev.azure.com/{orgName}/{projectNam}/_apis/build/builds?definitions=defintionId&$top=1&api-version=5.0-preview.5
```

Comment: another possible workaround if you know your definition Id , you can use 
`&includeLatestBuilds=true` for end point `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=6.0`

Answer (score 0):

you are omitting authorization this sample works for me

```
$uri = "your uri"
$pat = "your PAT"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "", $pat)))

$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo))
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Method GET
```