# How do you download a build artifact using Azure Devops CLI?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I got this far using `scoop install azure-cli`

```
az extension add -n azure-devops
az devops login
```

But I am not sure what to do next.  I am looking for something like this to output the contents of a file to stdout

```
az pipeline build get_artifact --project-id=xxx --name=myCI --artifact=drop --path=docker-compose.yml -o -
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/pipelines/runs/artifact?view=azure-cli-latest):

```
az pipelines runs artifact download --artifact-name
                                    --path
                                    --run-id
                                    [--detect {false, true}]
                                    [--org]
                                    [--project]
```