# How to download latest azure pipeline artifacts using Azure CLI through REST API?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, artifacts

I am using the below command to download artifacts

`az rest --url "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/artifacts?artifactName={artifactName}&api-version=6.1-preview.5"`

But this gives an error

**Can't derive appropriate Azure AD resource from --url to acquire an access token. If access token is required, use --resource to specify the resource**

I am new to Azure DevOps and doesn't have any support. I don't know what this resource is.
I tried giving --resource "latest" but then it gives an error

**The resource principal named tenant was not found in tenant named ...**

Please help me here

Comment: Did you login first to azure devops via commnad line?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below Azure CLI command to [download the Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?tabs=azure-cli&view=azure-devops#download-artifacts) As below:

```
az pipelines runs artifact download --artifact-name 'WebApp' --path $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/bin/WebApp --run-id '<run id here>'
```

Refer this  [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops#arguments) to find the arguments.

> Download artifacts produced by the current pipeline run, or
> from a specific pipeline run.   Options: `current`, `specific`
> Default value: `current`   Argument aliases: `buildType`

Please refer the below links for further details [To Publish & download latest azure pipeline artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?tabs=azure-cli&view=azure-devops#download-artifacts)  and please  find the similar thread [How to download the latest build artifacts from Azure DevOps programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54391120/how-to-download-the-latest-build-artifacts-from-azure-devops-programmatically).